# Quarkus - How to implement routing for Single Page Apps?

Tags: quarkus

How to implement routing in Quarkus if used with frontend frameworks like React, VueJS, Angular, etc?

For example, for any url "/xyz" the order of route evaluation should be:

1. Static file named "xyz", if exists.
2. Controller annotated with @Path("/xyz"), if exists.
3. 404 -> serve "/index.html"

Comment: Best practice for single page apps is to separate the SPA from the back-end, i.e. create a deployment artifact for the SPA consisting of the static files (Javascript, images, stylehssets etc.) and another artifact for the Quarkus backend (serving API requests only).

Comment: @Codo That's true, but if you want to use quarkus in a memory constrained environment like a raspberry pi then it doesn't make sense to run a separate service just for static files. It's better to do it in quarkus itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quarkus already does 1 and 2 for you.
For 3, you only need to implement a custom `NotFoundExceptionMapper`

```java
@Provider
public class NotFoundExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<NotFoundException> {
    @Override
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public Response toResponse(NotFoundException exception) {
        InputStream resource = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("META-INF/resources/index.html");
        return null == resource
                ? Response.status(NOT_FOUND).build()
                : Response.ok().entity(resource).build();
    }
}
```

Quarkus will use by order:

1. File `xyz`, if exists in `src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/`
2. Resource @Path("/xyz")
3. Custom `NotFoundExceptionMapper`

Comment: This exception mapper will not work in quarkus dev mode because there is a built-in exception mapper which is preferred. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64517266/12034237) and this [bug report](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/7883)

Answer (score 0):

Hijacking the NotFoundException is a workaround, why not use Vertx routes directly?
Create a catch all route (/.*) and make it the last route in the list, so the handler is called for all non existing paths.
Note: Make sure to check if the request already asked for the reroute path to prevent an infinite loop.

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class StaticRoute {

    private static final String reroutePath = "/index.html";

    void init(@Observes Router router) {
        router.getWithRegex("/.*").last().handler(rc -> {
            if (rc.normalizedPath().equals(reroutePath ))
                rc.fail(404);
            else
                rc.reroute(redirectPath);
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

The `GatewayResource` documented in this guide still works as of quarkus 3.8.1, without added dependencies:

https://blog.marcnuri.com/react-quarkus-integration-using-maven#gatewayresource-class

I replaced the `IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream)` with an `inputStream.transferTo(outputStream)` do drop the `commons-io` dependency as well.

You might want to check out some deprecation warnings as well.

It is referred to from the quinoa extension blog:
https://quarkus.io/blog/quinoa-modern-ui-with-no-hassle/