# ExceptionMapper will not invoked when JAX-RS exceptions thrown in Quarkus dev mode

Tags: java, exception, jax-rs, quarkus, exceptionmapper

I am working on a `Quarkus (2.7.1)`  application and facing with a problem which I cannot understand the reason.I write a class that implement `ExceptionMapper` interface to catch `RuntimeException` and I expect that any unhandled exception will be caught in this mapper as this is the only mapper I have in my application.

```
@Provider
public class BaseRuntimeExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<RuntimeException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(RuntimeException e) {
        return Response.status(HttpStatus.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
    }
}
```

The strange thing is that when I run the application in `dev` mode (running from ide), if an exception thrown by JAX-RS (e.g. `NotFountExction`) the mapper is not invoked and as a direct result, the exception Response object will return as http response. But the same code works as I expected if I run in production mode (directly run the generated jar). Can anybody give me any clue?

I define an exceptionmapper and I expect that any unhandled exception caught by the mapper. This works properly when the application run on production, but on dev mode the mapper is not invoked.

Comment: Seems weird... Could be a bug